# How do I create a dummy variable in R with non-numeric data?

Tags: r

I have a column of data listing various education levels from census data, they vary from "HS grad" to "Doctorate" to "9th" for the highest level of education the person received.

I want to create a dummy variable for whether someone is educated or not, and in the "educated=YES" category I want it to list the respondents with college or vocational school backgrounds.  I've tried using "&" but it won't group them.

```
C <- data.frame(educated=census$education=="Assoc-acdm" & "Assoc voc" & "Bachelors" & "Doctorate" & "Masters" & "Prof-school")
```

Anyone know how do group non-numeric responses?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example with sample input, expected output, and any attempts of your own so far.

Comment: I see you got a good answer, and `%in%` is a great way to do it, but you should also understand why yours doesn't work: (1) and is the wrong choice here, your education variable is never going to be both `"Assoc-acdm"` and `"Masters"` in the same line, you should use OR (which is a pipe in R `|`).

Comment: (continued) (2)  (2) The equality testing `==` is a binary operator, it can only test two things for equality. Instead of `census$education=="Assoc-acdm" | "Assoc voc" | ...` you need the `==` for every test, that is, `census$education=="Assoc-acdm" | census$education=="Assoc voc" | census$education== ...`. All this typing is what makes @josilber's solution with `%in%` much nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, you would want:

```
C <- data.frame(educated=(census$education %in% c("Assoc-acdm", 
              "Assoc voc", "Bachelors", "Doctorate", "Masters", "Prof-school")))
```